# Wavelet transformation to analyse time series

Tags: signal-analysis, python, wavelet, cwt, fast-wavelet-transform

I am new to wavelet transformation. I am learning it as a tool for signal processing. I have a time series that I want to analyze. I tried to learn wavelet transformation by applying it to a periodic function.

This is my code:

```
## Meta imports

import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

## Sine wave

## making time array

dt   = 1 / 1e3 ## interval between two consecutive time
t    = np.arange(1000)*dt
#frequency
f    = 100
# sine wave
sig  = 5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)

fs   = 1. / dt
w    = 8.       

freq   = np.linspace(50, 150, num = 100)
widths = w*fs / (2*freq*np.pi)

cwtm   = signal.cwt(sig, signal.morlet2, widths, w=w)
outz   = np.abs(cwtm**2)

plt.pcolormesh(t, freq, outz, cmap='jet')
plt.yscale('linear')
plt.ylim(min(freq), max(freq))

plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Freq (Hz)')
```

I got the following plots:

1. [image: Wavelet Transformation]
2. [image: Signal]

Now, I don't really know how to decide the widths, freq or w. I tried writing similar code for my data and cwtr returns 0 for all time.

I also tried using [pywt.cwt](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/cwt.html) but wasn't able to get the appropriate wavelet plot.

These are the resources I used to understand Wavelet transformation:

1. [scipy.signal.cwt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html)
2. [Wavelet analysis applied to the real dataset in a quick and easy way](https://www.earthinversion.com/geophysics/Wavelet-analysis-applied-to-the-real-dataset-in-a-quick-and-easy-way/#wavelet-transform)

I would like to understand the syntax of the wavelet transformation, how to decide widths, frequency etc. Also if you have any recommendations for resources, that would be awesome.

Comment: What's the goal of your analysis? What are you trying to find out?

Comment: I applied Fourier transformation on my data previously. Now, I am trying to conform our fft finding using wavelet transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`widths` is the array of scale parameters. For the CWT, scale parameter $a$ is inversely proportional to the corresponding Fourier frequency $f$, i.e.
$$
a=c_a/f,
$$
**where $c_a$ is a proportionality constant whose value depends on the specific wavelet function.** In the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT), we know
$$
2\pi/L\leq f< \pi N/L,
$$
where $L$ is the physical length of one signal, $N$ is the number of sampling points of the signal, and $\pi N/L$ is the Nyquist frequency. Therefore, the range of values of $a$ is
$$
c_a L/(\pi N)< a\leq c_a L/(2\pi).
$$

The proportionality constant $c_a$ can be determined in a variety of ways. For more information on this, I recommend you to refer to

- book: [The Illustrated Wavelet Transform Handbook](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781315372556/illustrated-wavelet-transform-handbook-paul-addison)
- paper: [Continuous Wavelet Analysis of Matter Clustering Using the Gaussian-derived Wavelet](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2022ApJ...934...77W/abstract)

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying what widths really mean. I appreciate the resources you shared.